# how to disable yarn error logs in stdout when running npm scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, package.json

I have an npm script in package.json that runs tests:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "tsc && node ./bin/test"
}
```

I run this with `yarn test`. I get the output of compile errors and this log from yarn:

```
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Is there a way to remove this log, because it covers up the screen, I can't see the compiler errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
yarn -s test
```

This command should silent the logs as `-s` option in yarn represents,

```
-s, --silent skip Yarn console logs, other types of logs (script output) will be printed
```